# Need some help with a bsod minidump please

Tags: bsod

I have posted a question in the windows 7 forums, but haven't got an answer yet. Because of the haste with this problem, I was so free to post it here too. Because of the usual quick answers I got here.

Windows 7 allows you to use a tool to include the dumps ans some system files which are used.

The files are located [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?vbhhcw978znwbiv) in a rar file.

I hope someone knows what the hs/sw problem is.

Is Windows 7 . . .
x64

- the original installed OS on the system?
  Vista
- an OEM or full retail version? 
  OEM
- What is the age of system (hardware)?
  3 to 4 years
- What is the age of OS installation (have you re-installed the OS?)

No, 5/6 months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be a driver error, since the errors were in the NT kernel... My first guess would be faulty RAM. Can't really help further, but here's some info from those dump files generated by WhoCrashed:

```
On Fri 17.9.2010 17:26:24 your computer crashed  
This was likely caused by the following module: ntoskrnl.exe  
Bugcheck code: 0x50 (0xFFFFF1200882A158, 0x1, 0xFFFFF80001FED455, 0x7)  
Error: PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA  
Dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\091710-40560-01.dmp  
file path: C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe  
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System  
company: Microsoft Corporation  
description: NT Kernel & System  
The crash took place in a standard Microsoft module. Your system configuration may be incorrect, possibly the culprit is in another driver on your system which cannot be identified at this time.   

On Fri 17.9.2010 17:20:38 your computer crashed  
This was likely caused by the following module: ntoskrnl.exe  
Bugcheck code: 0x3B (0xC0000005, 0xFFFFF80001FBE1D2, 0xFFFFF8800A503F30, 0x0)  
Error: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION  
Dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\091710-34710-01.dmp  
file path: C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe  
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System  
company: Microsoft Corporation  
description: NT Kernel & System  
The crash took place in a standard Microsoft module. Your system configuration may be incorrect, possibly the culprit is in another driver on your system which cannot be identified at this time.   

On Wed 15.9.2010 14:24:48 your computer crashed  
This was likely caused by the following module: ntoskrnl.exe  
Bugcheck code: 0x3B (0xC0000005, 0xFFFFF80001F771D2, 0xFFFFF8800A9C5F20, 0x0)  
Error: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION  
Dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\091510-53383-01.dmp  
file path: C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe  
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System  
company: Microsoft Corporation  
description: NT Kernel & System  
The crash took place in a standard Microsoft module. Your system configuration may be incorrect, possibly the culprit is in another driver on your system which cannot be identified at this time.   

On Tue 14.9.2010 16:49:28 your computer crashed  
This was likely caused by the following module: ntoskrnl.exe  
Bugcheck code: 0x3B (0xC0000005, 0xFFFFF80001FB91D2, 0xFFFFF88008232F30, 0x0)  
Error: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION  
Dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\091410-47720-01.dmp  
file path: C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe  
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System  
company: Microsoft Corporation  
description: NT Kernel & System  
The crash took place in a standard Microsoft module. Your system configuration may be incorrect, possibly the culprit is in another driver on your system which cannot be identified at this time. 

On Tue 14.9.2010 16:45:20 your computer crashed  
This was likely caused by the following module: ntoskrnl.exe  
Bugcheck code: 0x1E (0xFFFFFFFFC0000005, 0xFFFFF80001F731D2, 0x0, 0x42)  
Error: KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED  
Dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\091410-28766-01.dmp  
file path: C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe  
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System  
company: Microsoft Corporation  
description: NT Kernel & System  
The crash took place in a standard Microsoft module. Your system configuration may be incorrect, possibly the culprit is in another driver on your system which cannot be identified at this time.
```

Comment: As per the above analysis, the exception is: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION. Refer to the post http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957625.aspx for more details. It seems to be an issue with your hardware.

Comment: Also in the BSOD, the faulty module name is given. If you can look up on the name, you may get the culprit.